# How to connect remote mySQL db to flask app using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I want to connect to online MySQL DB to the flask app I made, so I can get rid of localhost stuff.

I have this code

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import os
import uuid
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash , check_password_hash

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'thisissecret'
# app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = os.environ['sqlite:////Users/confuapplication/PycharmProjects/untitled/.db']
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://saifaliunity:123123123!@saifaliunity.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com/saifaliunity$todo';
# app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

So well this is what localhost environment is, I have setup MySQL and python app online and want to set dbname, host, username, password to the flask app. But don't know how to do this.

After using the answer below this is the error log.

```
2019-02-26 10:16:54,896: Error running WSGI application
2019-02-26 10:16:54,900: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_app'
2019-02-26 10:16:54,900:   File "/var/www/saifaliunity_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
2019-02-26 10:16:54,900:     from flask_app import app as application  # noqa
2019-02-26 10:16:54,901: ***************************************************
2019-02-26 10:16:54,901: If you're seeing an import error and don't know why,
2019-02-26 10:16:54,901: we have a dedicated help page to help you debug: 
2019-02-26 10:16:54,901: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError/
2019-02-26 10:16:54,902: ***************************************************
2019-02-26 12:58:20,238: Error running WSGI application
2019-02-26 12:58:20,278: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_app'
2019-02-26 12:58:20,279:   File "/var/www/saifaliunity_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
2019-02-26 12:58:20,279:     from flask_app import app as application  # noqa
2019-02-26 12:58:20,279: ***************************************************
2019-02-26 12:58:20,280: If you're seeing an import error and don't know why,
2019-02-26 12:58:20,280: we have a dedicated help page to help you debug: 
2019-02-26 12:58:20,280: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError/
2019-02-26 12:58:20,280: ***************************************************
2019-02-26 12:58:21,842: Error running WSGI application
2019-02-26 12:58:21,843: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_app'
2019-02-26 12:58:21,843:   File "/var/www/saifaliunity_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
2019-02-26 12:58:21,843:     from flask_app import app as application  # noqa
2019-02-26 12:58:21,844: ***************************************************
2019-02-26 12:58:21,844: If you're seeing an import error and don't know why,
2019-02-26 12:58:21,844: we have a dedicated help page to help you debug: 
2019-02-26 12:58:21,844: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError/
2019-02-26 12:58:21,844: ***************************************************
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI` should be `mysql://username:password@server/db`, replace `username`, `password`, `server` and `db` with your values.

See the documentation for more details: http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/config/

Comment: So it should be in this function? os.path.expanduser() ? or passed without it?

Comment: You don't need `expanduser()` it is used to replace "~" with the fullpath of the user home directory.

Comment: but still its not connecting

Comment: @Debendra i have updated the question can you now help?

Comment: Activate your virtual environment first. Its not activated.

Comment: Thanks answer selected!